# Why isn't my images popping up when I touch the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, image

Can anyone help me, Im trying to make a simple app where you touch the screen and 4 images are randomly displayed. Problem is, when i tap the screen i don't get any image also I have no errors. Help!

Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var num1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "num1")
    var num2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "num2")
    var num3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "num3")
    var num4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "num4")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
        num1.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        num2.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        num3.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        num4.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

        let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        sceneBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = sceneBody
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let random = arc4random_uniform(4)

            switch random {
            case 0:
                self.addChild(num1)
                print("number 0")
            case 1:
                self.addChild(num2)
                print("number 1")
            case 2:
                self.addChild(num3)
                print("number 2")
            default:
                self.addChild(num4)
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are they supposed to be added? You didn't specify their position with CGPoint. You don't need to prefix addChild() with self by the way. Also, you don't notice but if the random happened twice with the same sprite, it would be adding the same sprite twice, and thus give you an error that num1 already has a parent.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that since I put the code in the touchesBegan function it would recognize that it is only when the screen is touched. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: yes only when the screen is touched, it would add any of the 4 variables. If you touch the screen again, it would add again any of the 4 variables. Keep tapping the screen and you will eventually get a NSException:Attempting to add a node that already had a parent.

Comment: So what could I put or use so that doesn't happen?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Are you only going to add those 4 images and that's it? Are you only going to add 1 of the 4 images and that's it? Or are you trying to make it add any of those 4 images as many times as the user keeps tapping?

Comment: Yes, the last part. as long as they tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting the position where each sprite should appear

Before each `self.addChild(...)` you should exec something like this

```
numX.position = location
```

and rearrange your touchesBegan method like this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    var location

    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }

    let random = arc4random_uniform(4)

    switch random {
    case 0:
        num1.position = location
        self.addChild(num1)
        print("number 0")
    case 1:
        num2.position = location
        self.addChild(num2)
        print("number 1")
    case 2:
        num3.position = location
        self.addChild(num3)
        print("number 2")
    default:
        num4.position = location
        self.addChild(num4)
        print("default")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test it but I have an error that set<UITouch> has no member anyObject.

Comment: What Swift version are you using?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean but I'm in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Try to define touch like this "let touch = touches.first as? UITouch"

Comment: Okay, let me test it.

Comment: It says 'Downcast form UITouch? to UITouch only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use !?' That was the error.

Comment: Try to remove the "?", Sorry I can't be more specific, I'm from mobile

Comment: It gives an error again saying that ' value of optional type UITouch? Not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! Or ?'.

Comment: I always use "for touch in touches { let userTap = touch.locationInNode(self) }"

Comment: Oh, didn't see it. Let me try that.

Comment: now it says 'Use of unresolved identifier "location"'. It means the case statements. saying num1.position = location.

Comment: You can use your source code as it is, but with two changes. The first is that you defined what I called "location" as "_", so you should fix this. The second is that at the end of the for cycle you should add a break command, otherwise your nodes will be added too much times

Comment: okay, i changed the _ and it still has the same error a while ago. Also, i will put the break.

Comment: Do you have a variable named "location"? That's why it's saying use of unresolved identifier. You could also try: for touch in touches { let location = touch.locationInNode(self) }

Comment: i tried it and same thing. Look at my new code. Should it go into view did load section.

Comment: @JosiahAgosto I updated my answer, please try it again. Location variable needs to be declared outside the for loop otherwise it will not be visible outside that scope.

Comment: i tried it and still says 'Use of unresolved Identifier'.

Comment: @JosiahAgosto, did you solve the issue? I just came back from holiday

Comment: Actually I haven't. I bought a swift off from Paul Hudson to see if he can solve my problem. He hasn't yet but I'm sure he will, his tutorials are great.

Comment: @JosiahAgosto, I edited my answer by changing "let location" to "var location", it shouldn't give the error now

Answer (score 0):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var handbag = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "HandBag")
var bible = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bible")
var watchtower = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Watchtower")
var awake = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Awake")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8)
    handbag.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    bible.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    watchtower.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    awake.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

    let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody
}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
        let random = arc4random_uniform(4)

        switch random {
        case 0:
            handbag.position = location
            self.addChild(handbag)
            print("number 0")
        case 1:
            bible.position = touch
            self.addChild(bible)
            print("number 1")
        case 2:
            watchtower.position = touch
            self.addChild(watchtower)
            print("number 2")
        default:
            awake.position = touch
            self.addChild(awake)
            print("default")
        }
    }
}
```